# <select> height in Chrome 53

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

After updating to Chrome 53.0.2785.101, I notice that the height of a `<select>` element is now a pixel less than before.

[image]

The below code will show height of 17 in Chrome and 19 in Firefox.

```js
document.write("height: "+$("#myselect").height())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option>Just one</option>
</select>
```

I can add padding to compensate, but then that changes the appearance in other browsers. Besides implementing Chrome-specific CSS, is there some way to normalize the height of the `<select>` element to have a consistent appearance across browsers? I tried a standard reset.css but that didn't make a difference.

**Extra credit**: what exactly did they change in Chrome 53 to effect this change? I didn't see it clearly listed in the changelog.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not understanding, but couldn't you just do `select { min-height: 19px; }` to ensure that it doesn't fall below 19px in any browser?

Comment: I'm honestly a bit confused by what's happening: https://jsfiddle.net/gpm8yu15/3/

Comment: Use `.outerHeight` or `.css.("height")` instead of `.height`.

Comment: Yeah, so outerHeight is now 19px in Chrome but 21 in Firefox. https://jsfiddle.net/gpm8yu15/5/

Answer (score 2):

Playing around with the CSS I found that I was able to remove 1 pixel different just by adding a standard `font-family` `font-size` and by setting the `border` to `0`. Removing the other pixel was a little more difficult. I ended up having to set `-webkit-appearance` and `-moz-appearance` to none and then apply a `min-height`. Here is an example of the code:

```
#myselect {
  background: lightblue;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: verdana;
  border:0;
  -webkit-appearance : none;
  -moz-appearance : none;
  min-height: 20px;
}
```

I [updated your js.fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpm8yu15/6/) if you want to test the results. BTW the reason why I had to set the `border` to 0 is because I had changed the JS to `outerHeight`. If you set it to `height` and remove the `border: 0;` it will show the same.

Comment: Upvote for some good effort, but doesn't setting appearance:none remove the down arrow so that it no longer looks like a select? Cutting off nose to spite face? :)

Comment: If we're going to get into doing browser-specific css, the simplest solution appears to be `select {-webkit-padding-before:2px}`: https://jsfiddle.net/gpm8yu15/7/

Comment: I no longer have easy access to older versions of Chrome... is all of this being caused by a change in Chrome's down arrow size? Then the padding probably needs to scale with the font size. Thoughts on how to do it universally for any font size? Man, this is going to cause some funny headaches for web developers around the internets.

Comment: @dlo thx for the upvote. yes you are correct adding the appearance none does remove the down arrow. Probably not the best solution but I was trying to find a way to easily normalize the select menu. I saw a similar question about the select menu and the other guy thought it was FF that changed their select menu not Chrome.

Comment: The reason I noticed this difference is that I have a page with some text and select fields that float left. Previously (and still in Firefox) the text and selects are the same height, so they wrap into rows nicely. But now in Chrome the text field is a bit taller than the select, so the text field's extra height "catches" the next row of fields, preventing them from floating all the way left. But indeed I would love to get access to current and previous versions of both browsers so I can confirm the precise change that happened.

Comment: I noticed the 2 main differences in the default styles between Chrome and Firefox are: (a) font-family [FF:MS Shell Dlg 32 / Chrome: Arial], and (b) padding [FF: 1px; Chrome: 0px]. So by setting explicit styles, I can now get the same result in both browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/gpm8yu15/11/

Answer (score 0):

I tried with given css and get into certain display issues. In a form if you have buttons, selects, input etc, putting css to select does not go well with other components like button, input (height mismatch).

I just put below css, and the look I got both in chrome and FF was really good. So wanted to share here.

```
select 
{
    min-height: 27px;
}
```

You can change min-height as per your need.